# MySQL: How to create table with auto incrementing column via script

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, create-table

I am new to MySQL and hope someone can help me with this.

**I want to create a simple table with two special settings:**

1. a two-column primary key including the columns "`de`" and "`location`"
2. an auto incrementing column "`tID`" that generates a unique ID,
   starting with 1

I tried the following (and several other approaches) but this always returns the below error:

**The SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE TranslationsMain (
    de VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    tID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    location VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    classes VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    info VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    sortOrder INT NOT NULL,
    en VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(de, location)
)
```

**The error message:**

```
"Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key."
```

It works if I leave the auto incrementing column ("`tID`") out so there seems to be something wrong here. 
Can someone help me with this ?

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: The auto_incement must be a part of the primary key.

Comment: @Jens: Thanks for that. Think we got it sorted with the answers provided below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SQL what the problem is auto increment must be primary key. Otherwise it will not work.

You can use like these. i think your problem will solve.

```
  CREATE TABLE TranslationsMain (
     de VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     tID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     location VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     classes VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     info VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     sortOrder INT NOT NULL,
     en VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(tID,de, location))
```

Comment: Thanks for this as well ! It works well with the answer from user1151316.

Comment: I voted you up already. :) I tested this and it works great. As this seems to be the more general approach I decided to accept this answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Try below query, I think this will solve your problem

```
CREATE TABLE TranslationsMain (
 de VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 tID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 location VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 classes VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 info VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 sortOrder INT NOT NULL,
 en VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(tID),
 UNIQUE(de, location))
```

OR

```
CREATE TABLE TranslationsMain12 (
     de VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     tID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     location VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     classes VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     info VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     sortOrder INT NOT NULL,
     en VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     unique(tID),
     primary key(de,location)
    )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - this works great as well ! As the other answer seems to be the more general approach I decided to accept that one but voted you up as well, hope that's ok. Thanks again !